# Use regular expression to look for exact phrase?

Tags: regex

I'm playing around with the pattern attribute in html5. It accepts a regular expression in order to deem a form-field valid or invalid.

I want a field to be valid if it contains the word John and nothing else. How do I do this with regular expression?

Comment: My suggestion: don't use regular expressions for this. This sort of thing can be handled with a basic `==` check.

Comment: @Palladium You can get in a lot of trouble comparing strings with `==`.

Comment: @Palladium I strongly disagree in this case. Obviously, the webb is not mature enough for html form validtion, but when it is, you get rid of a lot of complexity and code by using the pattern attribute rather than javascript.

Comment: But on the other hand, "using regular expression to look for exact phrase" is an oxymoron. The point of regular expressions is that it can find variable matches - and it's orders of magnitudes slower than bare comparison because of it. Furthermore, the `pattern` attribute isn't supported on all major browsers, and even then, it's always a better idea to validate the input using JS or PHP afterwards (in which case, you should definitely use comparison rather than regex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
pattern="^John$"
```

**Edit:** Actually, it looks like `^` and `$` are implied, so this would be sufficient:

```
pattern="John"
```

As pointed out by [Tim Pietzcker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20670/tim-pietzcker), to specify a case insensitive match, you would use the following:

```
pattern="(?i)john"
```